# Retrieving the asp.net textbox values that is inside fancybox

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, fancybox

Is this possible to retrieve the asp.net textbox values entered inside a jQuery fancybox into the query string? If yes, then how?

This is my code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".various3").fancybox({
            'width': '77%',
            'height': '100%',
            'autoScale': false,
            'transitionIn': 'none',
            'transitionOut': 'none',
            'href': '#searchPopupWindow'

        });
    });

protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            this.Search(txtAddress.Text, txtSuite.Text, txtZip.Text, moveDate);
    }
```

While debugging this code, I get the textbox values as `""` when inputted from the fancybox.

Comment: How is the textbox related to the current page where the fancybox is opened? Is it loaded as part of a new page (IFrame) in fancy box or is the HTML code part of the current asp.net page?

Comment: textbox is a part of the UserControl that is loaded inside a fancybox.

Comment: Your click event should be placed in the UserControl codebehind or you should expose those values from the textboxes through public properties on the usercontrol class. Then it would be `[UserControlID].txtAddress.Text`